# why it shows null on selecting a file from storage?

Tags: android, file, uri

I want to choose a pdf file on a button click and send that file to a url on another buttonclick. My issue is with selecting the pdf file. I am getting null in `"onActivityResult()"` method.

My code is

```
SelectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("application/pdf");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Pdf"), PDF_REQ_CODE);

        }
    });
```

ActivityResult method is

```
 @Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PDF_REQ_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            uri = data.getData();;
            SelectButton.setText("PDF is Selected");

        }

    }
```

But I am getting uri as null and getting null pointer exception when trying to get file path from uri.

Comment: have you added the persions in android manifest?

Comment: permissions are added to read and write storage

Comment: `But I am getting uri as null ` You are not getting an Uri but an Intent. `Intent data`. Please reformulate what you get.

Comment: `and getting null pointer exception when trying to get file path from uri.` You should not try getting paths from uries. And certainly not whan the uri is null. But where is that code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell me!

```
 Button button = (Button) x.findViewById(R.id.buttonStripText);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("file/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
}

@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(requestCode){
            case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
                if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                   fileName = data.getData().getPath();
                }
                break;

        }
    }
```

Comment: does it open to select the file,what does it say?

Comment: i choosed the file, but im not getting it on "onActivityResult()"

Comment: try displaying a string to see where it doesnt work,the URI